# EntityFramework Unable to determine composite primary key ordering

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm try to use EF code firts to create a system where you have a team that has one idea but the team can also have a portfolio of idea entities that belong to other teams. I'm having trouble add migrations and getting the relationships to work. Here is the code for the model:

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Portfolio = new HashSet<Portfolio>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolio { get; set; }
    public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }
}

public class Idea
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrentValue { get; set; }
}

public class Portfolio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IdeaId { get; set; }
    public Idea Idea { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Team and Idea are 1:1 and this relationship is fine. I think the problem is where I have portfolio relating to idea which doesnt have an Id field because its a 1:1 with Team it only has teamid.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Ideas_dbo.Teams_TeamId". The conflict occurred in database "VHolsDaqDb", table "dbo.Teams", column 'Id'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I can reproduce your migration issue.
But I did recreate your model in a unit test and had an issue generating the database.
Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type *'UnitTestProject1.Portfolio'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388)...*

So I added the 'Column' Attribute and the model generates fine.
[Column(Order = *n*)]
Maybe this can help you fix your migration

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (var context = new TestDbContext())
            {
                var teams = context.Teams.ToList();
                var ideas = context.Ideas.ToList();
                var portfolios = context.Portfolios.ToList();
            }
        }
    }


    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
    }

    public class Portfolio
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Idea")]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int IdeaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Team")]
        [Column(Order = 3)]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class Idea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Team")]
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("Idea")]
        public int IdeaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Idea Idea { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, great, I did try ordering but I did it slightly differently, let me give that a try.

Comment: Okay, I've gone database first now to save time and will have to readdress entity framework code first and perhaps do a pluralsight course. I've encountered so many problems and errors that are difficult to track down.